# In "The Boy" cartoon, was the cannon electromagnetic?

Tags: the-boy-2004

In "[The Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_(TV_series))" (AKA "Codename: The Boy") there was a genius kid, Toby Goodwin and his muscular minder, Bob Saint-Vincent who were shot from a **futuristic cannon** to trouble-spots all over the world.

**Does anybody remember if the cannon was electromagnetic?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the cannon appears to be some sort of compressed air contraption, like a gigantic air rifle. Note the compression chamber, the ultra-heavy bolting to prevent air escape and the blast of air/smoke that follows the ball out of the barrel. None of these are especially indicative of a *magnetic* railgun.